# Change color of page numbering for single pages or a period of pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I used `tikz` and `fancyhdr` to have my pagenumbering in colored circles. 
Now I want to change the color of the circle for one page. For example the 2nd page should have a blue color.
Would it also be possible to set options that the color changes for specific page numbers. For example blue for the first 10 pages, red for the next 20 and then yellow for the last 15?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=red,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}}     

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{}
\fancyfoot[OR,EL]{\circled{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\thepage}}}}
\fancyfootoffset[OR,EL]{20mm} % nach außen verschieben
\addtolength{\headheight}{0mm} % nach unten verschieben
\newlength{\headshift}
\setlength{\headshift}{0cm}
\addtolength{\headsep}{\headshift}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-\headshift}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can simply redefine your command

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=red,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}}
```

as needed:

```
\renewcommand*\circled[1]{% <====================================================
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=blue,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}%
%                                             ^^^^^
}
```

So with the complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=red,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{}
\fancyfoot[OR,EL]{\circled{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\thepage}}}}
\fancyfootoffset[OR,EL]{20mm} % nach außen verschieben
\addtolength{\headheight}{0mm} % nach unten verschieben
\newlength{\headshift}
\setlength{\headshift}{0cm}
\addtolength{\headsep}{\headshift}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-\headshift}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\renewcommand*\circled[1]{% <===========================================
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=blue,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}%
}
\lipsum
\renewcommand*\circled[1]{% <===========================================
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,rounded corners=2,fill=green,inner sep=1mm] (char) {#1};}%
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]